# iOS: How to check if video file is recorded using front or back camera

Tags: ios, video, video-recording, avasset

in iOS, how can we check if recorded video i.e. mp4 file is recorded using front or back camera.
I tried to get this information from AVAsset's videoTransform but this information is not in that.

Any Advice?

Comment: Have you checked the asset's metadata for this information? Photos include the information in that dictionary, so video may include it also.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't get it for video. Because video's metadata have no information for `lense` as available in image's metadata!!

you can get it for image in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` something like,

```
   NSString *lensModel = [[[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata"]objectForKey:@"{Exif}"]objectForKey:@"LensModel"];

NSLog(@"lenseModel for photo : %@",lensModel);
```

likewise you can get `metadata` for video by `AVFoundation` in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` something like,

```
    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]];

NSLog(@"asset metadata : %@",asset.metadata);
```

but it doesn't contain information about `lense (i.e front or back camera)`, so you can check it for image but not for video!